# authentication issue of IIS 6.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008, iis-6

I am using Windows Server 2003 + VSTS 2008 + .Net 3.5 + C# + ASP.Net + IIS 6.0. I host some files (wmv video file and html file) on the web server, I want to know whether there are any easy to use authentication approach to let user input username and password before they can access (I want to prevent anonymous access)? Since the web site has also aspx ASP.Net page, and I want to use an unified authentication solution for wmv, html and aspx page. If prefer any solution which utilizes username and password stored in SQL Server database which my application already has/use.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Mitch, I lost my Open ID acconut in the middle of my time here (do not know why), and it seems I have an account with the same email account and name here, but a different user, do not know why. I can not mark previous almost half replies as answered. You can check my recent answer mark rate is high.

Comment: "I can not mark previous almost half replies as answered." -- the erorr message is, you can not mark a quesiton asked by other people as answered. It is very weird.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Custom HTTP Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx) which are plugged into the asp.net pipeline.  You can effectively insert an authentication layer over any resources you wish to protect.

Comment: I think customer Http Module can only handle aspx request, can it handle non-aspx request, like html and wmv?

Comment: Oh you upgrade to Server 2008 and IIS 7

Comment: Sorry I can not. Looks like the only solution is to write ISAPI filter? No other easier solutions?

Comment: You should be able to map any extension you like to be processed by the .net pipeline and when that happens your custom http module will get fired for your wmv file and authentication can be managed from there.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you check out the [ASP.NET Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx).

It's the most "unified" authentication solution I've seen that's provided out-of-the-box for asp.net developers.

That way, you can use the default asp.net sql membership provider (or create your own implementation of it), have it set up your user/role tables (if you're using the sql membership provider), and then lock each folder down for authentication in your web.config.

I've been using the membership provider (as well as the roles provider) in many projects so far, under many different implementations.

Also, take a look at [How To: Use Forms Authentication with SQL Server in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998317.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I think your solution only works for aspx file, not working for html/wmv files. Any comments?

Comment: Take a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871
You can set authorization to individual files (whether aspx or not).

Answer (score 0):

When using IIS 6, if you want to leverage ASP.NET Forms Authentication to restrict access to non-ASP.NET files and resources (`.pdf, .gif, .jpg, .wmv` etc) , you would have to map a wildcard to the ASP.NET 2.0 ISAPI filter.

You can do this via:

`Web Site Properties -> Home Directory Tab -> Click Configuration -> Mappings Tab`

Click the "Insert" button and add the following path in the text box labelled "Executable":

> `c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll`